# How to compile QwtPlot3d with Qt5?

Tags: c++, qt5, qwt

Qt5 is released and the new Qt5.0.2 has MSVC2012 x64 version. Want to use QwtPlot3d with Qt5. In copilation, error of redefinition of GLdouble appears. Don't know the reason and how to fix it. Thanks.

Comment: Just download and follow the instructions to build it...

Comment: It didn't work. Redefinition of GLdouble. Don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Then it's time to redesign your question by providing relevant details and information on what you've tried so far, what did you achieve, and what are you currently stuck on. Your question in its current state is just impossible to answer.

Comment: which version of qwt are you using??

Comment: QwtPlot3d. I tried 0.3.0 and 0.2.7. Qwt is okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this is an OpenGL desktop vs OpenGL ES 2 issue. The Qt5 pre-compiled packages are built against ANGLE which provides OpenGL ES 2. Check [QT downloads page](http://qt-project.org/downloads/) if there is proper version(OPENGL 32bit) for you.

If you want to use desktop OpenGL on windows with Qt 5, you have to rebuild Qt yourself passing in -opengl desktop to the configure.bat script.

Answer (score 0):

It is of course not necessary anymore to re-compile QT yourself since they now also ship a prebuilt installer for opengl-desktop